# In void function, declaring a global variable doesnot make it global [C]

Tags: c, global-variables

I thought I know everything about global variables but now I can not solve that. I deleted some of codes.

```
int counter;//global variable for increase or decrease

int main(){
fun();
}

void fun(){
counter=999;
sad();
}
void sad(){
printf("Counter is %d\n",counter);
}
```

Output is 0. Why?

Comment: Perhaps you should say what compiler you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior. Both `fun` and `sad` lack prototypes, and your code calls them before they are declared. Therefore, the the compiler assumes that both these functions return an `int`. Since the functions are actually `void`, this results in undefined behavior.

Once you add prototypes, your code [runs perfectly](http://ideone.com/VtKvEu).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int counter;//global variable for increase or decrease

void fun(); // <<== First prototype

int main(){
    fun();
}

void sad(); // <<== Second prototype

void fun(){
    counter=999;
    sad();
}

void sad(){
    printf("Counter is %d\n",counter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work and actually works as expected in GCC 4.6, 4.7 and 4.8.

In order to run your code I had to had a few extra lines (declarations and include). Try compiling and running this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int counter;//global variable for increase or decrease

void fun();
void sad();

int main(){
    fun();
}

void fun(){
    counter=999;
    sad();
}

void sad(){
    printf("Counter is %d\n",counter);
}
```

If this gives you the same behaviour, then it must be a compiler bug.